# Hide the block on the "node/add/my_content_type" page

Tags: blocks

I created a content type. I want to show a block on all nodes of this content type except "node/add/my_content_type". I used the following PHP code:

```
global $node;
$arg1 = arg(1);
if ( $node->type == 'my_content_type') && arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric($arg1) ) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;  //default
```

Result: the block does show on all nodes of this content type, but also show on "node/add/my_content_type".

What I did wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's an extra bracket in your code after `'my_content_type'`.  Is that meant to be there?

Comment: It's a typo. It works after I removed this extra bracket. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$node = menu_get_object();
return isset($node) && $node->type == 'your_content_type' && arg(2) == '';
```

Edit: forgot about the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == "node" && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == "") {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if ($node->type == "your_content_type") {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Above code will show your block in all node pages of type "your_content_type"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a global `$node` variable. If you want to get the node object for the node currently being viewed, you should call [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7).

I would rather use the following code.

```
$node = menu_get_object();
return (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'your_content_type');
```